# How to filter datagridview between two datetimepicker in a C# windows application without a database?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datetimepicker

I want to filter datagridview between two datetimepicker **without the involvement of a database.** The datagridview has in-memory stored records. I'm using C# with .NET framework.

I have a DataGridView called "datagridview1", and 2 datetimepickers called "dateTimePickerFromDate" and "dateTimePickerToDate". So I need to search for the records in datagridview1, where the records are only between the 2 chosen dates, and I need to load the datagridview1. The date is based on the **Transaction Date** in the datagridview1.

[image]

Comment: There are many different ways to do this and all pretty much all will be dependent on “how” the data is read into the grid. It is unknown how the grid is filled with data. Does the grid use a `DataSource`? If not, you should consider using one as it will make things easier. Typically, the grid has a `DataSource` and you would simply filter the `DataSource`. The “type” of `DataSource` used (List or Table) will dictate “how” to filter the `DataSource`. How is the grid filled with data?

Comment: For a `DataTable`, you will want to look at the `DataView` Class. You can make a new `DataView` from the table like… `DataView dv = new DataView(Table)` … the `DataView` has a `RowFilter` property to filter the view. Once you have the filtered `DataView` you can use it as a `DataSource` to the grid.

Comment: Hi, I have used a DataTable: `DataTable dataTableExpense = new DataTable("table");` Grid is filled with data using a form filled by the user: `dataTableExpense.Rows.Add(description, amount, currencyType, date, recurringStatus);`

Comment: Thank you very much @JohnG for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a DataTable with minimal data which loads a BindingSource needed for filtering. Two variables are used, replace them with your DateTimePicker controls.

Code in Button1 toggle the filter.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public partial class DemoForm : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingSource _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
        public DemoForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            _bindingSource.DataSource = MockedData();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _bindingSource;
        }

        public DataTable MockedData()
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("TransactionDate", typeof(DateTime));

            dt.Rows.Add(1, new DateTime(2022, 9, 3));
            dt.Rows.Add(2, new DateTime(2022, 6, 3));
            dt.Rows.Add(3, new DateTime(2022, 10, 1));
            dt.Rows.Add(4, new DateTime(2022, 9, 11));
            dt.Rows.Add(5, new DateTime(2022, 9, 12));

            return dt;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // replace the two vars with DateTimePickers
            var lowDate = new DateTime(2022, 9, 1);
            var highDate = new DateTime(2022, 9, 12);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_bindingSource.Filter))
            {
                _bindingSource.Filter = $"TransactionDate >= '{lowDate}' AND TransactionDate <= '{highDate}'";
            }
            else
            {
                _bindingSource.Filter = "";
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Karen Payne. I got it now -)